# Motivating Grothendieck Toposes generated by Souslin Objects

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I am currently reading about the independence of the *continuum hypothesis* from ZFC following the topos theoretic proof given in Chapter VI.3 of MacLane Moerdijk's Sheaves in Geometry and Logic.

The goal is to construct a new model of set theory $\mathscr{S}'$, in which CH fails. For this we need a set $B'$ right between the set of natural numbers $\mathbb N'$ and $\mathcal{P}'(\mathbb N')$. We assume that our given set theory $\mathscr{S}$ does not admit such a set (otherwise there is nothing to prove). To construct $\mathscr{S}'$ we realize the required injections by means of a presheaf topos $\mathsf{Psh}(\mathbf{P})$ on the *Cohen-poset* $\mathbf{P}$ of finite approximations. We then make this presheaf topos into a boolean topos in the universal way by passing to the *Cohen-topos* $\mathscr{S}'=\mathsf{Sh}(\mathbf{P},\neg\neg)$. So far so good.

It is the final step I fail to properly motivate. To make the argument work we need the canonical functor $\mathscr{S} \rightarrow \mathsf{Sh}(\mathbf{P},\neg\neg)$ sending a set $X$ to the constant sheaf $\hat{X}$ to preserve strict cardinal inequalities. This can be shown by means of the following theorem:

> Let $\mathscr{E}$ be a Grothendieck topos generated by *Souslin-objects* (objects $X$ with the property that any family of pairwise disjoint subobjects of $X$ is at most countable). Then the canonical functor $\widehat{(-)}$ preserves strict cardinal inequalities.

While I can follow the proof given by MacLane Moerdijk, I don't understand the intuition behind this theorem. I tried to read about the *Souslin-property*, but I could not find much more on it than the fact that it originated in Souslin asking for an alternative characterization of the real numbers. I don't understand why it reappears in this particular form in the proof of the independence of CH. Phrased differently:

> Why does the Souslin property appear in the theorem above? Is it a necessary consequence of $\widehat{(-)}$ preserving strict cardinal inequalities (hence being a characterization)? Or is it maybe obvious from the definition of the Cohen-poset that it having the Souslin property will have some strong consequences for sheaves on it?

I hope this question is specific enough to be on Math.SE, since I feel like it might have an obvious answer for someone with more experience in set/topos theory than myself. Anyway I thank you for your time and answers.

Comment: I didn't read everything in detail but I think that $\widehat{(-)}$ always preserves strict cardinal inequalities between large enough cardinals, for any topos. It seems that the Souslin property appears only at the very end of the proof of the theorem and that if we are only concerned with cardinals bigger than $α$, we can replace "countable" by $α$ in the Souslin property.

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer to express the proof using the internal language? In the notations of the book you have $U_{s,t} = \{x∈X\,|\,f(x)(s)=t\}$.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting generalization of the argument, but still I don’t see why I should have the idea to consider the souslin property, if I am interested in preserving strict cardinal inequalities. For example I would be satisfied, if it were some kind of general theme to consider the souslin property for sheaves on finite approximations to a thing we want to construct. But as I said, I could not find much about it…

Comment: Are you familiar with the "traditional" formulation of forcing?  This looks like an equivalent of an argument using the countable chain condition (should really be called the countable antichain condition).  I think in topos terms, the idea wold be that the Souslin condition implies if you have a sheaf isomorphism between the constant sheaves of cardinals $\kappa$ and $\lambda$, then there can't be too many different values of $\alpha \in \kappa$ under that isomorphism, so you get $\lambda \le \aleph_0 \cdot \kappa \le \lambda$.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no background in either set or topos theory (I know a fair bit of category theory, but I don’t think this involves forcing). So you are saying the countable (anti)chain condition is something which naturally arises in classical forcing? Do you maybe know a good reference for learning about it (if any std reference will do: what is your favorite set theory book)?

Comment: I don't know about "naturally", but yes, in classical forcing, the countable chain condition argument is a standard technical result implying non-collapsing of cardinals.  Unfortunately, I don't have a good reference to give out (I learned set-theoretic forcing in a class with no textbook).

Comment: Well Cohen (or whoever came up with it) surely had some intuition for it, which is what I am asking for. Anyway thanks for your input! I notice that I have focused too much on the word souslin and not so much on CCC and will investigate in this direction…

Comment: I don't know if it might be helpful to see an example where cardinals *do* get collapsed.  A standard example would be if you use $\mathbb{P}$ being the set of injective functions from a finite subset of $\aleph_0$ to $\aleph_1$, ordered under inclusion (or reverse inclusion, depending on your convention).  Then you can define a sheaf isomorphism $\hat{\aleph_0} \to \hat{\aleph_1}$ by sending $n$ to the gluing of $\alpha$ on $\{ f \mid f(n) = \alpha \}$ which cover $\mathbb{P}$ in the $\lnot\lnot$-topology.

Comment: Thank you very much for this counterexample! I will then also meditate about whether I can motivate the CCC based on this observation…