# Topos-theoretic proof of the consistency of CH

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, set-theory, topos-theory, forcing

I hope this is not a duplicate, if so please let me know.

So in MacLane Moerdijk‘s book *Sheaves in Geometry and Logic* it is shown that there is a boolean, two-valued topos with nno and choice, in which the continuum hypothesis ($\vert \Bbb N \vert < \vert \cal{P}(\Bbb N)\vert$) fails, ie. that it satisfies NCH. But they only *state* that Gödel has proven the consistency of CH with ZFC, so that in summary CH is independent from ZFC. I find this kind of unsatisfying, since Gödel worked in a setting quite different to topos theory and would like to know, whether CH is consistent with boolean two-valued topoi with nno and choice (which I will call $\mathsf{Set}$–like). In other words

> Is there a topos theoretic proof of the consistency of CH with $\mathsf{Set}$-like topoi (written down somewhere)?

As far as I can tell (I have absolutely no background in set theory) Gödel‘s original proof modifies and plays with the membership relation of ZF. This doesn‘t sound like it carries over to topos theory.

A very naive idea would be, that maybe any $\mathsf{Set}$-like topos $\cal{E}$ has a $\mathsf{Set}$-like subtopos, which satisfies CH. But this would kind of imply that the free $\mathsf{Set}$–like topos (if such a thing even exists) has to satisfy CH. I don‘t know why, but this feels like too strong of a statement.

Another idea would be that, given a $\mathsf{Set}$–like topos $\mathcal{E}$ satisfying NCH, we can turn it into a $\mathsf{Set}$-like topos satisfying CH, by forcing (no pun intended) all strict cardinal inequalities $\Bbb{N} < K$ (for those $K$ strictly smaller than $\cal{P}(\Bbb N)$) to become isomorphisms. Maybe we can modify the filter quotient construction (which I don‘t really know yet) or make a localization / sheafification kind of argument. But since I am fairly new to topos theory, I don’t have made up my mind yet and would like to ask for references or other inputs.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I am not an expert in typos theory or set theory, but surely Gödel‘s proof shows that the class $L$ of constructible sets satisfies the axioms of ZF and hence is a topos. Any model of ZF is a topos.

Comment: Ok maybe the question is not phrased perfectly. I don’t want to ask if there is a topos  satisfying CH (of cause there is, if you believe in set-theory and Gödel), but rather if given a $\mathsf{Set}$-like topos we can enforce CH by categorical methods…

Comment: Note that forcing can also produce models where $\mathsf{CH}$ *holds*. That's not how the consistency of $\mathsf{CH}$ was historically established, but it does work. So there's no need to replicate Godel's argument, and no additional issue.

Comment: As Noah says, we can establish independence of CH by forcing alone. But the question remains: is there any topos-theoretic version of Gödel's constructible universe L?

Comment: @NoahSchweber I didn’t know that. What are the forcing conditions then? Finite approximations to inverses for the unwanted cardinal inequalities? Can we do all of them at once or do we have to do this inequality after inequality in possibly transfinite induction? And how do we actually show that the forcing construction does not introduce new unwanted cardinal inequalities? (the whole Cohen topos is about proving that that can happen, so we better be careful)

Comment: @JonasLinssen It's a lot simpler than you're expecting: the standard way to do it is with **countable** partial functions from $\omega_1$ to $2^{\aleph_0}$. This poset is countably closed, so adds no new reals. This is actually *easier* to analyze than the $\neg\mathsf{CH}$ version, which uses the somewhat more subtle behavior of the *countable chain condition*.

Comment: "Can we do all of them at once or do we have to do this inequality after inequality in possibly transfinite induction?" Maybe you're mixing up $\mathsf{CH}$ and $\mathsf{GCH}$? Forcing $\mathsf{GCH}$ is indeed harder, we need class (Easton) forcing, but it's still doable.

Comment: @NoahSchweber No I wasn’t thinking of GCH (though I would like to know how to force it in topos land as well, but this is not the question here). In my mind to force CH, the construction should 1. collapse all existing nontrivial cardinals between $\Bbb N$ and $\cal{P}(\Bbb N)$ and 2. not introduce any new ones. I don’t really know how to show it (with the poset you provide), since my only experience with forcing is the one on NCH explained by MacLane Moerdijk and I don’t have a full intuition for why they do it the way they do it (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4451166)

Comment: @JonasLinssen (I'm not very familiar with category-theoretic forcing, so this is framed in the standard set-theoretic context:) You don't need to worry about forcing adding new cardinalities, since (as long as the ground model satisfies $\mathsf{ZFC}$) forcing never does that. More precisely, forcing never adds ordinals and preserves choice so if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ holds in the ground model then everything in the new model is in new-model-bijection with something old. The issue is adding new reals: we need "old $\mathbb{R}$" and "new $\mathbb{R}$" to coincide. Countable closure does this directly.

Comment: My understanding is that the category-theoretic translation of a (simple) set-theoretic forcing argument is pretty direct: we should always look at $Sh_{\neg\neg}(\mathbb{P})$ for the poset $\mathbb{P}$ in question, and the same combinatorial properties of posets (e.g. chain/closure conditions) play the same-ish roles. On a more subjective note, if you're comfortable with the purely set-theoretic approach it should be easier to tackle the category-theoretic one, but learning the category-theoretic one from scratch is likely going to be rough going *(since all the motivation is set-theoretic)*.

Comment: @NoahSchweber thank you very much for your help so far! I don’t really understand your claim about every new set being isomorphic to some old one. It seems to suggest that the change of model is an equivalence of categories. But then this equivalence should preserve powersets $\Omega^X$, which is obviously false for the Cohen-forcing…

Comment: @JonasLinssen Dropping the category theory for a moment, all I mean is this. Suppose $M$ is for simplicity a countable transitive model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ and $M[G]$ is a forcing extension of $M$. Then for each $a\in M[G]$ there is a $b\in M$ and an $f\in M[G]$ such that $M[G]\models$ "$f$ is a bijection between $a$ and $b$." This is because $\mathsf{Ord}^M=\mathsf{Ord}^{M[G]}$ (trivial, doesn't require choice) and $M[G]\models$ "Every set is in bijection with an ordinal" (equivalent to choice in $M[G]$ which follows from choice in $M$ - if we don't assume choice in $M$ this step breaks down!).

Comment: Note that the bijection $f$ lives in $M[G]$, not $M$; this is true even if we assume $a\in M$ *(what if $M[G]\models a\equiv b$ but $M\models a\not\equiv b$? note that this is exactly what happens when we force $\mathsf{CH}$ as per the above!)*. Broadly speaking, the "one-sidedness" here prevents the fact above from giving an equivalence of categories between ${\bf Set}_M$ and ${\bf Set}_{M[G]}$ (try to write an equivalence). Incidentally, I **strongly recommend** first studying forcing set-theoretically - the category-theoretic approach is a generalization of an already quite difficult topic.

Comment: Ah I see. If I understand you correctly, you are saying that the construction is not full on morphisms ($M[G]$ has more (iso)morphisms), so $M\rightarrow M[G]$ can be as essentially surjective as it wants, it cannot be an equivalence… Sorry for insisting on the categorical language. Category theory is my chosen way to understand topics I don’t know yet and it seemed to me that with a good understanding of sheaf- and cat.-theory forcing could be one of the things where it worked best. Maybe I am mistaken, we will see… Thank you very much for your help!